# iOS: class instances connection and architecture with multiple UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, class, uiviewcontroller

I have a theoretical-practical question. I can't understand how I must do. I have a class let's call them DataManager that manage all plist writing-reading things and I need to get access to plist (i.e. work with that DataManager class) from different UIViewControllers.

I also have one class, I call it ModelManager, that is work with all kind of "utilities classes", include my DataManager. ModelManager works only with one complex UIViewController right now, let's call it MainUIViewController for clearness. And for now, I thought that all calls from UIViewControllers will be comes to ModelManager and from it to end-call classes. But now I'm confused.

Here is an illustration of my architecture:

[image]

I'm see different approaches and don't know how to decide and if there is some rules or guides for that. So, here is my choices:

1) I add some interface to ModelManager and from my another UIViewController (not a MainUIViewController) allocate and initialise it.

2) I add some interface to ModelManager and create a property with reference to ModelManager in another UIViewController and when segues performs set this property from MainUIViewController.

3) Work with DataManager itself and allocate and initialise it from another UIViewController

4) Work with DataManager itself and create a property with reference to DataManager in another   UIViewController and when segues performs set this property from MainUIViewController.

Which approach is correct?

I know that this is some kind of depends from developer which approach to choose, but I never read and didn't find any tutorial or guide of how to develop multi-class architecture.

Ask me about any circumstance that you want to know.

Comment: I'm not really clear on the question exactly.  Some more concrete examples would be nice....

Comment: @nhgrif I'll draw a picture :)

Comment: It would be better, I think, for the `ModelManager`, `DataManager`, etc, to all be instantiated by the `AppDelegate` rather than a `ViewController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a singleton or you can instantiate one instance of the class in your app delegate and pass it around to all your view controllers via @propertys on each controller. There's no right answer, it's mostly a matter of preference. I prefer to make my ModelManager/DataManager type classes singletons, but a lot of people are rabidly opposed to singletons. However, if you work with Cocoa for any length of time you'll find that it's full of them (NSUserDefaults, NSFileManager, UIDevice, probably some others I'm forgetting).

Here's a good example on how to create singletons: http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

BTW: Once you have your singleton, learn how to use KVO to make your view controllers respond to changes in the model.  It's pretty fantastic once you get the hang of it.  http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/

Comment: I don't know whether it's considered good practice or not, but what about having a `ModelManager @property` on his `AppDelegate`.  Then you don't even have to pass anything around.  You can simply do `[(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].myModelManagerProperty` (and could `#define` that big long part into something more managable like `UIAppDelegate`.

Comment: My opinion is if you're going to do that, you might as well use a singleton. It's the same effect and it's a lot tidier. You don't have to include AppDelegate.h everywhere. Conceptually I like the purity of keeping the app delegate completely focused on app delegate concerns.

Comment: @jsd after first time initialising, singleton is always in the memory, right? In which circumstances this could be very bad? Thanks, for your answer, now I know much more than before and I will use singleton class.

Comment: A singleton doesn't necessarily STAY in memory forever.  All it does is return a reference to an already instantiated object of itself rather than creating a new object any time you try to create an object.  This object can be de-allocated just like any other object if there are no more references to the object.

Comment: @nhgrif that is incorrect. if you look at the implementation i linked to in my answer, you'll see that it is using a static "sharedMyManager" variable. The class itself retains the variable, so it will never be dealloced. flinth yes this means the singleton uses memory forever. Plan accordingly!